# try/catch to check a json doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json

I want to check if a string received is JSON and I tried the following code:

```
try {
    JSON.parse(-10); // Same for "-10"
}catch(e) {
    console.log('inside catch');
}
```

The code never goes inside the catch block! Why is it so?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: Not sure why you wait for an error when converting `-10` to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A plain value is valid JSON](http://www.json.org/). That's why you're not getting `'inside catch'` logged.

```js
document.write(JSON.parse(-10));
```

This isn't valid JSON, however:

```js
try {
    JSON.parse('{');
}catch(e) {
    document.write('inside catch');
}
```

As you can see, the `try`/`catch` is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think -10 is valid to JSON.parse

```
JSON.parse('{}');              // {}
JSON.parse('true');            // true
JSON.parse('"foo"');           // "foo"
JSON.parse('[1, 5, "false"]'); // [1, 5, "false"]
JSON.parse('null');            // null
```

```js
try {
    var a = JSON.parse("{[]]]["); // Same for "-10"
  console.log(a);
}catch(e) {
    console.log('inside catch');
}
```